# Como fazer metodo subdominio automatico

Tags: dns

Queria fazer 1 website que faria subdomínios para endereços de servidores de voz
poe exemplo fazia um domínio `ts3dominio.dnsempresa.com` e esse endereço iria para porta padrão 9987 ou mesmo uma porta customizada.

O projeto teria pernas para andar se eu soubesse como fazer isso.

Eu queria fazer isso com meu dominio `.tk` que é um domínio grátis.

Exemplo desse serviço:

- https://www.ts3dns.com/
- http://www.ts3dns.eu/

Comment: Isso depende da onde seu DNS esta hospedado, se ele fornece alguma API, etc.

Comment: eu uso o freenom.com mas ele esta ligado a cloudflare sabes se funciona?

Comment: Espera tem muitos apis sim mas n sei qual deles faz o trabalho http://www.freenom.com/pt/freenom-api.html

Comment: Você deve usar a API register. Mas provavelmente terá que configurar o cloudflare também... ele deve ter API também para isso, mas nunca mexi com ele, mal sei como funciona =/